# How to modify an ABPerson instance using PyObjC?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos, applescript

I am trying to do some repairs to a very large address book on OS X. I would like to do this programmatically, as it would be a very intense effort to do by hand. On a hunch, I thought I might use PyObjC for this, given my familiarity with Python.

I'm able using PyObjC's module AddressBook to poke around, but I can't seem to make any changes:

```
>>> import AddressBook
>>> ab = AddressBook.ABAddressBook.addressBook()
>>> p = ab.people()[0]
>>> p.isReadOnly()
True
>>> p.valueForProperty_('First')
u'Foo'
>>> p.setValue_forProperty_('Bar', 'First')
False
>>> p.valueForProperty_('First')
u'Foo'
>>> type(p)
<objective-c class ABPerson at 0x7fff76e01ab8>
```

My first question is can I edit / modify contacts/persons this way? My second question is, for this kind of work, I can also effect changes to contacts using the ScriptingBridge to talk to the Contacts App, using either AppleScript or even PyObjC (or others). Would this be a better method than using the "low-level" API?

**EDIT**
I tried a few more methods, plain old AppleScript, and Python using the ScriptingBridge. All of my methods to script modifications to contacts fail, even when I call the save() method of the address book. Do I need to edit some system setting to allow contacts to be scripted?

**EDIT**
For the record, I am running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.3

Comment: Also asked on apple.stackexchange: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/94199/using-applescript-to-modify-contacts-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. Looking at errors in the console after running the above script, I saw many errors looking like:

```
AOSKit ERROR: (-) RAF: Invalid url -- https://[myemail]@webdav.facebook.com/[myfbid]/contacts/
```

(email and id changed of course). I have a 'Facebook' account set up in OS X preferences. By an educated guess, I deleted this Facebook OS X account, and then re-added it. After that, the above script works correctly.